# PHP default_charset NOT changing

Tags: php.ini, charset

I have modified the php.ini file shown in the Loaded Configuration File value of phpinfo() to set the default_charset to UTF-8:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

[image]

However, when I re-run the phpinfo(), I see no change whatsoever. What else do I need to do to make sure this thing gets set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to restart apache afterwards.

Comment: Why does PHP not load it's config when it "runs". It works on my localhost.

Comment: If you use mod_php (the apache module), you have to restart (or at least reload) apache to get the new configuration running. You don't have to do this for php-cli, fcgi or php-fpm.